# Can I get Google Maps v3 to draw polylines independently?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I'm trying to animate the path of a tracked vehicle on a Google Map (v3 API). I have 4 polylines: one being a grey background line to indicate the entire route, and 3 more to indicate the previous hours worth of tracking data (red for the past 10 minutes, orange for 10-30 minutes and yellow for 30-60 minutes).

Even though I've set the zIndex correctly for the polylines, as I create the new animated lines and destroy the old ones the grey background line keeps overlapping the other lines (I don't touch this polyline during animation).

It also seriously reduces the performance of the animation, if I disable the grey line the performance is just fine.

I believe what's happening is that Google Maps is using one canvas element to draw all the polylines that intersect that rectangle, so it has to redraw all of my polylines in that rectangle, not just the ones I'm animating. Is there any way to get Google Maps to put them on separate layers so it only redraws the ones I want to redraw?

Update: I've created a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/chby9xob/) that performs pretty well, but does demonstrate the background line overlapping the other lines.

HTML:

```
<button>Animate</button> <div id="slider"/>
<div id="map" style="height: 600px; margin-top: 20px;"/>
```

Javascript:

```
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.destinationPoint = function(brng, dist) {
   dist = dist / 6371;  
   brng = brng.toRad();

   var lat1 = this.lat().toRad(), lon1 = this.lng().toRad();

   var lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(dist) + 
                        Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));

   var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist) *
                                Math.cos(lat1), 
                                Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(lat1) *
                                Math.sin(lat2));

   if (isNaN(lat2) || isNaN(lon2)) return null;

   return new google.maps.LatLng(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());
}

Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   return this * Math.PI / 180;
}

Number.prototype.toDeg = function() {
   return this * 180 / Math.PI;
}

var range_lines = {
    red: null,
    orange: null,
    yellow: null
};

var range_colors = {
    red: '#ff0000',
    orange: '#FFA500',
    yellow: '#FFFF00'
};

function onSlide(e, ui) {
    var end_minute = ui.value;
    var start_minute = Math.max(0, end_minute - 60);

    var line_points = [];
    var last_range = null;
    var last_point = null;

    for (var minute = start_minute; minute < end_minute; minute++) {
        var diff = Math.abs(end_minute - minute);
        var range = '';

        if (diff <= 10) {
            range = 'red';
        } else if (diff <= 30) {
            range = 'orange';
        } else {
            range = 'yellow';
        }

        if (range != last_range) {
            renderLine(line_points, last_range);
            line_points = [];
            last_range = range;
        }

        if (points_by_minute.hasOwnProperty(minute)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < points_by_minute[minute].length; i++) {
                line_points.push(points[points_by_minute[minute][i]]);
                last_point = points[points_by_minute[minute][i]];
            }
        }
    }

    marker.setPosition(last_point);
    renderLine(line_points, last_range);
}

function renderLine(line_points, range) {
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: line_points,
        strokeColor: range_colors[range],
        strokeWeight: 3,
        map: map,
        zIndex: getZIndex(range)
    });

    if (range_lines[range] != null) {
        range_lines[range].setMap(null);
    }

    range_lines[range] = line;
}

function getZIndex(range) {
    switch (range) {
        case 'yellow':
            return 10;
        case 'orange':
            return 20;
        case 'red':
            return 30;
    }
}

var points = [];
var points_by_minute = {};
var map;
var marker;
var interval;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var start_point = new google.maps.LatLng(51.3767, -0.0960);
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(51.3767, -0.0960);
    var minute = 0;
    var bearing = 0;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()

    for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                bearing += Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            } else {
                bearing -= Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }

        if (i != 0 && i % 12 == 0) {
            minute++;
        }

        if (!points_by_minute.hasOwnProperty(minute)) {
            points_by_minute[minute] = [];
        }

        points_by_minute[minute].push(points.length);

        point = point.destinationPoint(bearing, 0.01);
        points.push(point);
        bounds.extend(point);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        if (i != 0 && i % 12 == 0) {
            minute++;
        }

        if (!points_by_minute.hasOwnProperty(minute)) {
            points_by_minute[minute] = [];
        }

        points_by_minute[minute].push(points.length);

        var latJitter = Math.random() / 10000;

        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            latJitter = -latJitter;            
        }

        var lngJitter = Math.random() / 10000;

        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            lngJitter = -lngJitter;            
        }

        point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            points[4999 - i].lat() + latJitter,
            points[4999 - i].lng() + lngJitter
        );
        points.push(point);
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], {
        center: start_point,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    $('button').button().click(function() {
        if (interval) clearInterval(interval);

        var value = $('#slider').slider("option", "value");

        if (value == $('#slider').slider("option", "max")) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        $('#slider').slider("option", "value", $('#slider').slider("option", "min"));

        interval = setInterval(animate, 10);
    });

    $('#slider').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: minute++,
        step: 1,
        value: 0,
        change: onSlide
    });

    new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: points,
        strokeColor: '#cccccc',
        strokeWeight: 1.5,
        map: map,
        zIndex: 1
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: start_point,
        map: map
    });
});

function animate() {
    var value = $('#slider').slider("option", "value");
    value++;
    $('#slider').slider("option", "value", value);
    if (value == $('#slider').slider("option", "max")) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide the code as it's for work, it's also several hundred lines long and requires a lot of data. I'll try and reproduce the issue in a sample, but I was hoping someone would at least know about how Google Maps is drawn and how issues like this can be worked around.

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that will help. Without the code it's hard to tell...

Comment: Code added with a link to JSFiddle.